# PowerPoint vba macro - Copy Text Box text to note -need to also copy font & font color

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a current macro that works well.  It deletes all of the current notes in the PPT slide - then copies every shape that has text to the slide notes.

I need one more "tweak"--- when the text is copied to the note area, I need to also copy the current font, font color, size, etc.

Is there a way to do this?

Many thanks!!!

```
Sub Copy_SlideShapeText_ToNotes()

  Dim curSlide As Slide
  Dim curShape As Shape
  Dim curNotes As Shape
  Dim oSh As Shape

'delete all notes in receiving slides
  For Each curSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
    curSlide.NotesPage.Shapes(2) _
          .TextFrame.TextRange = ""
  Next curSlide

  For Each curSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oSh In curSlide.NotesPage.Shapes
      If oSh.PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderBody Then
        Set curNotes = oSh
        Exit For
      End If

    Next oSh
    For Each curShape In curSlide.Shapes
      If curShape.TextFrame.HasText Then
        curNotes.TextFrame.TextRange.InsertAfter curShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text & vbCr
      End If
    Next curShape
  Next curSlide

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub Example()
' Assume you have two rectangles on slide 1 and no other shapes
' And that the first rectangle has text with various formatting
' This will pick up the text from the first rectangle, run by run,
'    and apply the text AND its formatting to the second rectangle

    Dim oSrc As Shape
    Dim oTgt As Shape
    Dim x As Long
    Dim oRng As TextRange

    Set oSrc = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1)
    Set oTgt = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(2)

    With oSrc.TextFrame.TextRange
        For x = 1 To .Runs.Count
            With .Runs(x)
                ' Add the text from the current run to the second rectangle
                ' and get a reference to its range in oRng
                Set oRng = oTgt.TextFrame.TextRange.InsertAfter(.Text)

                ' now format the text in oRng to match the same range
                ' from the original
                oRng.Font.Name = .Font.Name
                oRng.Font.Bold = .Font.Bold
                oRng.Font.Color = .Font.Color
                ' add other properties as required, stir well

            End With
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Copy_SlideShapeText_ToNotes()

  Dim curSlide As Slide
  Dim curShape As Shape
  Dim curNotes As Shape
  Dim oSh As Shape
  ' New variable:
  Dim oRng As TextRange

'delete all notes in receiving slides
  For Each curSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
    curSlide.NotesPage.Shapes(2) _
          .TextFrame.TextRange = ""
  Next curSlide

  For Each curSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oSh In curSlide.NotesPage.Shapes
      If oSh.PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderBody Then
        Set curNotes = oSh
        Exit For
      End If
    Next oSh

    For Each curShape In curSlide.Shapes
      If curShape.TextFrame.HasText Then
        Set oRng = curNotes.TextFrame.TextRange.InsertAfter(curShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text)
        With oRng
            .Font.Name = curShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Name
            .Font.Bold = curShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Bold
            .Font.Color.RGB = curShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Color.RGB
            ' other properties as required
        End With
      End If
    Next curShape
  Next curSlide

End Sub
```

Comment: This works great as long as the text has the same fonts and format.   Unfortunately my text is a mixture of different fonts, some bold, some italics, some red.    Any thoughts on managing many different fonts?      What is interesting is that if I select the text manually and paste, all of the different fonts, formats, etc. are copied properly.

Comment: If you iterate through the .Runs collecton of the .TextRange of each shape and copy each .Run's text and formatting to the notes page rather than all of the text at once, that should handle it.  A new .Run starts with every formatting change in the text.

Comment: Thanks Steve.   The font can actually change on a character by character basis - so should I set my "oRng" for each character and copy?  For example, I may have one sentence that is Arial with bolded words, the next sentence may start with a wingding character that is red, then change back to arial black.         Is there a way to capture the whole set of characters with the individual properties and then re-create?    Again - it is interesting that a manual "copy and paste" does this -- but challenging to do programatically ;0

Comment: I think that's what you'll want to do, yes.  Each .Run returns a TextRange, by the way.  Offhand I can't think of a way to do it otherwise.

Comment: Steve - I don't have a .Run --- can you give me a code example or more details?  Thank you!